# Create Table Issue in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating table in MySql by using the coomand, `create table person ( id int, name int)`. Actually, I want to create table person if there exists no person table in database. Can anybody help me, how to acive this ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84330/mysql-create-table-if-not-exists-else-truncate

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069179/if-table-does-not-exist-execute-a-long-query/9069391#9069391

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id INT, name INT)`?

Answer (score 2):

[The manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) says that you should use

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id int, name int);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id int, ...);
```

See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF NOT EXISTS`:

create table if not exists person ( id int, name int).

[See MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)